# SSL reverse proxy for legacy application binary transfers on sockets

Tags: c++, apache-flex, ssl

I'm struggling to find a reverse proxy http->https like for binary sockets.

There is a [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) server which offers this kind of SSL tunneling but just for the http protocol.
Basically I work on 4'th layer TCP/IP with binary data. Between flex/AIR client and c++ server.
I can wrap sockets in C++ without problems, but this is a problem for flex side.

Any advice welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/)?

Comment: The examples how to run decrypt service (stunnel -p ... ..) seems not up to date. Simplifies I don't know how to run it as a decrypting server. However I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use stunnel:

```
sudo stunnel3 -c -f -d 127.0.01:4443 -r secureServer:443
```

After running the above command clients that don't support SSL can connected to port 4443 on my local host.  This connection is then tunneled over SSL to secureServer.

Comment: It seems like the recent version doesn't support all Your parameters, however I'm struggling to run it other way round - secure connecton to unsecure.